# Does static library avoids name mangling issues?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries, porting, visual-c++-6

I have a C++\MFC application written in Visual Studio 2003 SP1 links to an external static library "SomeExtStaticLib.lib". I also include the header files provided with "SomeExtStaticLib.lib" to create the objects in my application.

SomeExtStaticLib.lib is a static library built with VC6.

Now, I am migrating my application to Visual Studio 2008.

I have very basic question.

Should I also migrate the "SomeExtStaticLib.lib" to VS2008 compiled one?
When I tried to use this VC6 compiled "SomeExtStaticLib.lib" in my VC9 compiled application it **did not** give any linker errors. I was expecting at least some name mangling issues.

Are static libraries eliminating the name mangling issues?

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't one of static vs. dynamic linking, nor really of name
mangling.  The issue is one of binary compatibility for everything used
in the interface.  Thus, for example, unless I'm badly mistaken, the
definition of `std::string` changed between VC6 and VC9, with a
different layout.  So if any of the code uses `std::string`, you'll have
to recompile, or get strange and unexplicable errors at runtime.

In general, it's best to assume no binary compatibility as soon as
different versions of the compiler, or even different compilation
options are involved, unless the vendor guarantees otherwise.  (Although
some common sense is in order: you can freely mix options which only
control warnings, for example.  But beware of `/D`s which cause added
debugging code to be generated or not.)

Comment: it's not only the interface - memory allocation & deallocation has probably changed as well. This means as soon as you free memory allocated in the lib or the lib frees memory allocated by you, undefined things happen. This includes exceptions, which are allocated where they are thrown and freed where they are caught.

Comment: @Tobias Langner This depends on how you've compiled and linked.  If you're using `/MD` or `/MDd`, this shouldn't be a problem.  (At least, I don't think so.)

Answer (score 1):

If the application is unchanged it needs the same set of symbols from the library. And hence perhaps you can link to the library compiled with VC6.0. Name mangling is not the concern at all unless both the application and library are the same as the compatible(working) ones in VC6.0.

***Should I also migrate the `SomeExtStaticLib.lib` to VS2008 compiled one?***
There are compatibility problems between VC6.0 and visual 2008. So **YES** you should rebuild yor library with Visual 2008.

Just because you can link to the library as is doesn't mean it will work correctly.

***Are static libraries eliminating the name mangling issues?***
Not really. They are not doing anything special at all.

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries have nothing to do with or without name mangling.... if your code is C++ there is mangling, and if its C (or extern "C" in C++) then there is no mangling. As long as the library and the code that link it agree, there's no problem to link in the library.