# Is it safe to pass shared_ptr and other STLs between dlls and so's if built using the same compiler and compatible compiler flags?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, shared-ptr, abi

I see articles stating that it isn't safe to pass STLs and shared_ptr between dlls because

1. that can lead to memory corruption and
2. They could have different C++ runtime implementations and therefore cause undefined behaviour.

Question 1: Is this true if I compile both libraries with the same compiler version and flags? Considering that the C++ runtime would be the same and dlls are usually allocated memory from the virtual address space of the calling process are these two points still valid.

Question 2: I see solutions referencing to creating the object in one dll on the heap and passing a custom destructor that cleans it up on smart_ptr creation and passing that along so it can be safely deleted from the second first dll that created it when the reference is lost. When is this need? This isn't ABI stable is it? Isn't this needed only the dll created the object in it's own address space and you wouldn't want another dll to delete from it? That's not the default is it?

Question 3: Is this equally relavent to static libraries talking to each other say built with different compiler versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete real problem fromusing std library types between dlls.

Same std library, two dlls.

Dll1 defines a class Foo.

Dll2 wraps the Foo in a shared ptr.  The destruction code of Foo is type erased with cose in Dll2.

Dll2 is unloaded.

Last reference to shared ptr goes away.

Program crashes.

Now, I have fixed this; you need to be really careul about where you created shared ptrs. If you have code that does this widely (say, a copy on write pointer), you have to call into Dll1 to get fresh shared ptrs whenever you make a new one.

That being said, we still do it.  I am just saying it isn't free.  This same problem would occur even if I reimplemented shared ptr myself; it is a problem with code that generates code on the fly (ie, templates with rype erasure) and atttaches it to values in a multi-dll environment.

Answer (score 0):

(1-2) DLLs have separate heaps. So allocating in one dll and deallocating in another causes a crash. This isn't just a `shared_ptr` or STL only issue but a very general problem and it imposes a lot of difficulties. `shared_ptr` can be used to solve this: in `shared_ptr` you can specify deleter function that calls delete in the correct dll.

(3) Different compiler versions can cause serious issues when you link libraries together especially as static libraries. Imagine some implementation differences in STL. It easily leads to a crash or code corruption. For instance, in MSVC linking debug with release might cause a crash in `std::string`. One of warnings that MSVC does is when usings atomics - they say in VS2015 there was a bug in them for certain types of atmics so don't link with libraries from that version of VS.

To link different compilers/versions safely dlls are necessary. Usually, one tries to implement a very basic interface in DLLs so it will be as ABI safe as possible.

Comment: I don't agree with some of these statements but do see value in the rest. 

Std::shared_ptr 's delete is type erased and therefore the default implementation achieves the same as passing a custom deleter. What is not safe is a unique_ptr where it is not type erased. 

"To link different compilers/versions safely dlls are necessary. Usually, one tries to implement a very basic interface in DLLs so it will be as ABI safe as possible. " 

The fact that it is a DLL adds 0 benefit. to link different compiler versions you need a stable ABI which I think is true for static libraries too.

Comment: @rstr1112 "The fact that it is a DLL adds 0 benefit..." you are absolutely wrong. Unlike static library DLL doesn't expose any link symbols unless it is explicitly declared. So one can have completely different STL versions used in two different dlls. While using it in static library will cause instant code corruption as all symbols are exposed and duplicates will be randomly removed.

Comment: @rstr1112 to use very different complilers or even languages one usually creates C-style interface for external usage. Exposing specific library classes in a dll could cause issues as user might be importing same library but a different version which would cause collision. So there is a certain tradeoff of how much ABI/library is shared between the compilers/codebases versus how advanced the interface is.

Comment: Basically you're saying, You can interract between dynamic libraries via a stable C ABI and avoid the corruptions but you can't if you use components not part of the C ABI. 

The exact same is true for static libraries too , You can interract between static libraries via a stable C ABI and avoid the corruptions but you can't if you use components not part of the C ABI. 

Hence dll = 0 benefits with respect to ABI stability.

Comment: @rstr1112 I believe you are right about the deletion in `shared_ptr` but there is still the issue that user might have a different version of `shared_ptr` from the dll. Although it should be fine if compiler/STL coincide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342171/does-static-library-avoids-name-mangling-issues answer stating issues don't get resolved just by using dll.

Comment: You are assuming ABI conpatible version of shared_ptr itself which isn't guaranteed unless the compiler is the same. So default deleter or not compilers have to be the same. The only thing it gives you is if memory is allocated in a dll it is freed in the dll. Does not give you ABI compatibility I don't think.

Comment: @rstr1112 no if you perform link to a static library that **internally** uses a shared_ptr of different version will cause code corruption. Static library exposes all symbols both external and internal.

Comment: the same is true for dlls too. sharing shared_ptr across dlls is not ABI compatible and is not C-style interface.

Comment: I take it back I see what you mean. Interesting.

Comment: But my statement still stands, unless you use same compiler, custom deleter or not you can't pass shared_ptr across dlls.

Comment: @rstr1112 I never stated one could share `shared_ptr` across dlls. Only that one could use one to manage them. Modern C++ interface for ABI safe code consists of C-style interfaced dll with a bunch of headers that create C++ wrappers around the dll simplistic interface so one could utilise it much easier.

Comment: "shared_ptr can be used to solve this: in shared_ptr you can specify deleter function that calls delete in the correct dll." you talk here about custom deleter to make sure it was safely deleted from the same dll. This contradicts your last statement. You agree that interfaces need to be ABI safe and at the same time you also talk about passing shared_ptr between dlls which is not ABI safe.